# PC crashes when attempting to install Ubuntu

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

Whenever I boot from the USB drive and select "Install" or "Try Ubuntu without installing" I get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRAFT.jpg

The "text" or white lines scroll for a few seconds and then they stop, the monitor loses signal and the keyboard and mouse turn off.

So far I tried Ubuntu 17.04 iso, 16.04 iso. 2 different USB drives and tried both Rufus and UUI to no avail.

Comment: Try setting the `nomodeset` parameter and retry `Try Ubuntu` mode.

Comment: I had a computer with an offboard video card that showed this issue. So I removed the card, installed Ubuntu and after the first update, I reinstalled the video card. It worked.

Comment: I can't remove the card because my PC has no onboard video.